# Ads acting strange?

Tags: bug, advertising, 403-forbidden

I was on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), and I noticed an ad that I wasn't particurlarly interested in, but thought I'd take a look. Immediately after clicking it, I was taken to link 1. Perhaps it is something to do with my computer, but I don't have another computer to test with. I'm unsure if this is the correct place or way to report this, but I think it's something I should let someone know about, right?

Anyway, upon returning to Arqade, again I clicked on link 2 to see if it was just the first link, and it took me to a blank page.

I just checked, and I don't have ads enabled anyway using the reduced ads privilege.

This isn't exactly bothering me; I just don't know whether it's something I should report.

Also, I am in Spain right now, which is not where I'm usually located (Ireland). Might this have something to do with it?

Please let me know if I'm in the correct place to report this and if I even should have.

[image: 403 Page]

I also re-enabled Advertisements via the prefences section and clicked another link. Was taken to the 403 error.

Link 1: [Stack Overflow Jobs](http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjst-DqloofxTpvxqkbethnkUO_ujbgoGoo2EpspPHxlqgkPeAyq98afRhcXcRJEYScGrYvCBd43V0yxeQ2XkHN0kWe8h-9fK0GOSifBtA1Jvpd5QXgzK9D2lo_9hkvp_Kepk8bS2hZxcCBD-p-b69eC5cRxrMKw57lnNJoBS8NPXW2aAlaWZwnHSj25fE7-8cW3haFCkgNbMLeUPdGOUgO8L4dcv8MLROjDY-wOVsQkIdH9VCLiqLHDVbkJy4EeqPWlBSmg9ijDQfkhdfIJiVASoJdRZezYZMeJA7Rc70kmaBQkH5Ek&sai=AMfl-YRaKMfAN-ES6Vr5Onoq7jyxz-sA62FiyP-wcQ_uQECSje-j4Pd0mJnZeGK618U7DXd_h-eMW3aVx7CvnW-CD7urHUeZlMnU2sGQrRS5hHQ3poPE3IoVkA2lOK5Q&sig=Cg0ArKJSzABwauGvmJL0&adurl=http://stackoverflow.com:80/jobs/remote%3Futm_source%3Dwebsite%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_content%3Dmpu_4%26utm_campaign%3Dhouse_ads_ROS_SU&nx=73&ny=224)

Link 2: [Stack Overflow For Teams](https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsu17CUTWltMYYIsPmORv6UQAxKVF9fo9vx3AVyHR7SXjktAwI5N4QRyeloihy-HV9OGNffBkAS3JLVihexA1XldSmx15v9fv14h7dljLNPmIGKpdXcnmuvph8alDRLMDR4PykFpoGLMN6S2_f4GiXCyJmEuBo6ou7awSp0pXxdXqLjC1JUtjUeDEBlDxOHvY4Xkdp-9PzFSBBVeidYG6ZGsY9B7aCebYAOqf0MdWSKpK-3ZFEDwnGab-ZsoVVkXXexYoNclR8Su_R6Gi-sAV77I2iSEzmJE_AXcambv2LyzIXKaLvg&sai=AMfl-YQkEyuzH-iTuEcdPavHdz2EqDf5RjRWLC6ldKW73l_PNR9X5htQEIUaFat0zuqKxwRNGbw0ldYoRZw6PIhhhGY5VxYFylb0Ij5eHm9aQ6Ays8AF4N23P574qLVy&sig=Cg0ArKJSzKR-LXhZpN3l&adurl=https://stackoverflow.com/teams%3Futm_source%3Dso-owned%26utm_medium%3Dhouse-ad%26utm_campaign%3Dteams-slack-launch%26utm_content%3D300x250-even-easier&nx=152&ny=99)

Comment: NoRepro: When I click on link 1 or 2 in your question neither is a blank webpage.  Going to Arqade and clicking/reloading never serves an AD that leads to a blank webpage. Location: North America.

Answer (score 3):

Things to look at:

1. Ad-Blocker installed
2. Pi-Hole Server running
3. Alternate DNS Server configuration causing requests to be filtered or hosts to be unreachable (similar to Pi-Hole server)
4. Webserver unreachable for you (have you tried traceroute-ing to the server?)
5. Firewall settings
6. HOSTS file configured to block access to server
7. Proxy denying access to web server (ISP, Hotel, Router set up to block access to ad servers)

Best of luck.